# Query with MySQL incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

I have error on my `Query`

> 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column 'dms.HrAttLogsFormatted.ScanIn' which is
>   not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

**Query :**

```
SELECT
    Employee.Id as Id,
    Employee.FingerId as FingerId,
    Employee.Name as Name,
    Departement.Departement as Departement,
    EmployeeShift.Shift as Shift,
    ScanIn
FROM
    HrEmployee as Employee
    LEFT JOIN HrEmployeeShift as EmployeeShift 
        ON Employee.ShiftId = EmployeeShift.Id
    LEFT JOIN CmDept as Departement 
        ON Employee.DeptId = Departement.Id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            TableEmployee.FingerId,
            ScanIn
        FROM
            HrEmployee as TableEmployee,
            HrAttLogsFormatted
        WHERE
            TableEmployee.FingerId = HrAttLogsFormatted.FingerId
            AND DateIn = '2019-11-04'
        GROUP BY HrAttLogsFormatted.FingerId
    ) AS HrJoinLogs 
        ON Employee.FingerId = HrJoinLogs.FingerId
WHERE
    Employee.Status = 1
    AND Employee.Flag = 1
    AND Employee.ShiftId = 1
    AND ScanIn is NULL
GROUP BY
    Employee.Name
ORDER BY
    Employee.Name ASC
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Why are you using `group by` at all? There is no aggregate function in your query.

Comment: There are no aggregations in this query so a group by is inappropriate - what are you trying to do.

Comment: Side note: properly formatted queries are *much* easier to understand. I formatted your query, please consider doing it yourself next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read about MySQL's [notorious non-standard handling of GROUP BY. Here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Second, it looks like you're using `GROUP BY` to eliminate duplicates from your result set. That procedure is questionable. In my opinion it's unacceptable when your query deals with other peoples' money.  You may want to use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead. But, your best bet is to figure out the intended logic of this query and rewrite it to deliver that logic more explicitly.

If you still think you need `GROUP BY`, look at a result set from when your query worked, before you upgraded to a more modern version of MySQL.  You will see that all rows of your result set's ScanIn column are NULL, because your query says `AND ScanIn IS NULL`.

So, grouping by ScanIn won't hurt anything.  Add `, ScanIn` to both `GROUP BY` clauses.